# Javascript Image Window

Tags: javascript, gallery

Sorry for the title, I could not come up with a better one.

What I need is some way to open a re-sized image with Javascript in the same window, sort of like how Facebook works. I already have the gallery code ready so I don't need a fully featured java script gallery.

Here is what I want it to do:

- Work across all browsers
- Open the full sized image on click
- The opened window can never be larger than the screen size, so if a user opens an image larger than his screen it will be cropped
- The window closes when the user clicks on the window's X button or clicks outside the window

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something like http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery would better help you in doing it.

Check [this](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Also [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) would help you.